# Getting HTML before first <br/> tag

Tags: php

I've been trying to extract the content of a variable before the first break tag occurs in php.

e.g

```
$content = "this is my content <br /> as it continues <br /> another break tag";
```

I want to get the part before the first 
 tag and store it in a variable $first.  Thus for the above example, $first should contain "this is my content"

Any idea how to do this in php?  I'm stuck with the split() php function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$content = "this is my content <br /> as it continues <br /> another break tag";
$parts = explode("<br />", $content);
$first = trim($parts[0]);
```

explode function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

> Split a string by string

trim function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

> Strip whitespace from the beginning
>   and end of a string

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = explode('<br />', $content); // split on tags
$var = trim($parts[0]); // remove extra whitespace
```

This will only work if there are no other `<br />` tags before the first part your trying to capture. and that the format of `<br />` doesnt vary. IF it does then youd have to use a regex or if the entire html string is complex youd need to use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 1):

Or,

```
$part = substr($content, 0, strpos('<br />', $content));
```